# Normal map artifacts from baking separate objects

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I tried to add screws to the gun i was making, and now that Im trying to bake it into the normals im running into problems.

[image]

The circled things are probably from the screws, but I have no idea what is causing it on the bake.My best guess is because the screws are overlapping the body, this is the result. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think it would be good if you could add the steps you are using to bake multiple objects.

Comment: Ray, would you like me to post the blend?

Comment: just in case: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2ZiQtohl3tmME84bmgxWjRwUVU

Comment: I don't know enough about baking to be able to know if a blend is needed, I just think if you add the process you are using to bake, that might help.

Comment: Oh ok, well, the blend file is there for anyone who is willing to help me

Comment: Update: I found out if I have a screw baked to the left side only, the artifact shows on the right. So I didnt know if this was helpful but just putting that out there